# Need to replace alpha numeric characters by space and create new column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert the following

```
Column 1          Column 2
ABC, Company   ABC Company
TA. Comp       TA Comp
```

How can I get Column2 in sql where I am removing all ',' '.' to space.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

Comment: ...then change the title. The title says "replace alpha numeric characters." The comma and the dot are not alpha numeric; the letters ABC are.

Comment: ...and do some research before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
with testdata as (
  select 'ABC, Company Inc.' as col1 from dual
  union all
  select 'TA. Comp' as col1 from dual
)
select trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col1, '[[:punct:]]',' '), ' {2,}', ' ')) as col2
from testdata;
```

Output:

```
ABC Company Inc
TA Comp
```

Assuming punctuation is what you're trying to blank out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+', '')
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Are you sure? This will change `'ABC, Company'` to `'ABCCompany'`, no? How about numeric characters?

Comment: @mathguy:-  Yes thats correct(Update my answer). I just went with the specific case which OP has presented. There could be other scenarios as well where it could go wrong but I am staying with Op's question.

Comment: You still didn't fix the first problem I pointed out. Your code will replace the substring `', '` with nothing - it will delete not only the comma, but also the space. It is probably better to replace with exactly one space, not with an empty substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (val) as 
(
  select 'ABC,. Cmpany' from dual union all 
  select 'A, VC' from dual union all
  select 'A,, BC...com' from dual
)
select 
  val, 
  replace(replace(val, ',', ''), '.', '') x , -- one way
  regexp_replace(val, '[,.]', '') y           -- another way
from t
;

VAL             X          Y        
--------------- ---------- ----------
ABC,. Cmpany    ABC Cmpany ABC Cmpany
A, VC           A VC       A VC      
A,, BC...com    A BCcom    A BCcom
```